# Angular -Java script Push operator is not retaining existing vales when API call happened

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, push, angular-services

I'm trying to retain vales of the user when API call happened .
below is the scenario One user has access to three continent and each continent has some countries (which user has access)

```
ngOnInit(): void {
   
          this.getcontinentByUserId(event);
    
  };



 getContinentByUserId(userId: string) {
    if (userId === undefined) {
      return;
    }
    const ContinentNames= [];
    this.continentService.getcontinentByUserId(userId).subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.continents= data.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
      this.continents.forEach(con=> ContinentNames.push(con.name));
      this.ContinentNames= ContinentNames.toString();
      for (const index of data) {
        this.getCountryByContinentIdByUserId(index.id, userId)
      }
    });
  }



 getCountryByContinentIdByUserId(ContinentId: string, userId: string) {
    if (ContinentId=== undefined || userId === undefined) {
      return;
    }
    const Contrynames= [];
    this.contryService
      .getContriesByUserId(ContinentId, userId)
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
        this.counties= (data.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name)));
        this.counties.forEach(min => Contrynames.push(min.name));
        this.contries1= Contrynames.toString();
       for (const index of data) {
          this.getStatesByContryIdByUserId(index.id, userId);
        }
      });
  }
```

I tried to push data into contry its pushing but when its trying to add next set of contries to push last added items are deleting from continentNames and Contrynames

Answer (score 0):

You have assigned blank array to **Contrynames** everytime. Assign the value of **contries1** to **Contrynames** as below and make sure that contries1 is array type.

```
getCountryByContinentIdByUserId(ContinentId: string, userId: string) {
if (ContinentId=== undefined || userId === undefined) {
  return;
}
const Contrynames= this.contries1;
this.contryService
  .getContriesByUserId(ContinentId, userId)
  .subscribe((data: any) => {
    this.counties= (data.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name)));
    this.counties.forEach(min => Contrynames.push(min.name));
    this.contries1= Contrynames;
   for (const index of data) {
      this.getStatesByContryIdByUserId(index.id, userId);
    }
  });
```

}